# How to deal with optional selections in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, selection, onchange

I have a list `View` that takes a `Binding` to a selection.

```
struct SomeList: View {
    @Binding var selection: SomeType?

    var body: some View {
        Button("Selected") {
            selection = SomeType()
        }
    }
}
```

On the other side I like to know when a selection is made so I can do something with the result.

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State private var showSomeList: Bool = false
    @State private var someListSelection: SomeType?

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Sheet") {
            showSomeList = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSomeList) {
            SomeList(selection: $someListSelection)
        }
        .onChange(of: someListSelection) { //ERROR! NO OPTIONAL ALLOWED
            //Do something with the some list selection.
        }
    }
}
```

How can I react on the selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the `onChange` modifier:

```
func onChange<V>(of value: V, perform action: @escaping (_ newValue: V) -> Void) -> some View where V : Equatable
```

Its completion handler expects an argument, so you must use the correct implementation:

```
.onChange(of: someListSelection) { newValue in
```

In addition, for `onChange` to identify when your property changes it needs the type to have some unique way of saying what is equal to what.

Hence `SomeType` must conform to `Equatable` as you can see in the top function.

Comment: That explains it, however, what is the advised way to still be notified when the selection changed?

Comment: Using `onChange` is the best one.

Comment: Somehow I received errors, but now that I test it again, optionals is not a problem anymore. No idea what went wrong. Thanks for helping me tho. I will mark yours as the answer.

Comment: This is due to poor Swift error handling. It shows an error that you cannot use optional, but it usually means that you have an error inside the closure. 

Answer (score 2):

There is a [`sheet` API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)) which is triggered by an **item** rather than by a `Bool`

```
struct SomeType : Identifiable { let id = UUID() }

struct MainView: View {
    @State private var someListSelection: SomeType?

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Sheet") {
            someListSelection = SomeType()
        }
        .sheet(item: $someListSelection) { item in
            SomeList(type: item)
        }
    }
}

struct SomeList: View {
    let type: SomeType

    var body: some View {
        Text("Foo")
    }
}
```